# AWS S3 Photos stop working, trying to work with url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Junior dev, new to AWS.

User uploads an image.

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (photoToUpload) {
       
        const slug = `${id}-${photoToUpload.name}`;
        uploadPhoto(slug, true).then(url => {
                                                    
          setPhotoUrl(url);
        });
      }
    })();
  }, [photoToUpload]);
```

This works fine. What I'm noticing is that after a certain amount of time, the image no longer loads, and I get a 400 Bad Request error for the image.

My thinking is that it's somewhere with the image url expiring.

I've been trying to figure out possibly a better way use the image from AWS? Any direction or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have shown code for **uploading** images, so what do you mean by "after a certain amount of time, the image no longer loads"? How are they 'loading' the image?

Comment: Anonymous user and HTTPS GET?  Signed URLs expire.  Unsigned URLs require the ACL set to public / everyone for the file, and the bucket policy also must allow anonymous reads.  If it is some other kind of access, you need to explain the details in your ticket (edit it, don't add comments), "it doesn't work" does not give us useful information.